# A generic logger in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, template-meta-programming

I've created a simple logging system that I'm planning to use and I've tried out some modern C++ features to make it generic. First I've made a log class that represents a single log message:

```
struct log : std::stringstream
{
private:
    template <typename Level, size_t I = 0, typename... Stamps>
    static inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Stamps), void>::type
        __stamp(log& l)
    {
    }

    template <typename Level, size_t I = 0, typename... Stamps>
    static inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Stamps), void>::type
        __stamp(log& l)
    {
        l << std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Stamps...>>::Get<Level>();
        __stamp<Level, I + 1, Stamps...>(l);
    }

public:
    template <typename Level, typename... Stamps>
    static log& emit()
    {
        static log l;
        __stamp<Level, 0, Stamps...>(l);
        l << ": ";
        return l;
    }

    template <typename T>
    log& operator<<(T el)
    {
        *((std::stringstream*)this) << el;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename Logger>
    void Flush()
    {
        Logger::Log(str().c_str());
        clear();
    }
};

template <typename Logger>
std::ostream& endlog(std::ostream& out)
{
    ((log*)&out)->Flush<Logger>();
    return out;
}

typedef Logger<ConsoleSink> DefaultLogger;
std::ostream& endlog(std::ostream& out)
{
    ((log*)&out)->Flush<DefaultLogger>();
    return out;
}
```

And I've created the main logger:

```
template <typename... Sinks>
class Logger
{
private:
    static std::tuple<Sinks...> s_Sinks;

private:
    template <size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
    static inline typename std::enable_if<I == sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
        __Log(const char* msg)
    {
    }

    template <size_t I = 0, typename... Tp>
    static inline typename std::enable_if<I < sizeof...(Tp), void>::type
        __Log(const char* msg)
    {
        std::get<I>(s_Sinks).Write(msg);
        __Log<I + 1, Tp...>(msg);
    }

public:
    static void Log(const char* msg)
    {
        __Log<0, Sinks...>(msg);
    }
};

template <typename... Sinks>
std::tuple<Sinks...> Logger<Sinks...>::s_Sinks;
```

An example usage would be:

```
log::emit<Info, LevelStamp, SeparatorStamp, TimeStamp>() << "Hello, Logging " << 3 << endlog;
```

Now I can see a lot of problems with my own code, for example because of my emit function is defined with variadic stamps, there's no way to define a default overload for it so if I always want the same stamps, I have to type them out. Another is that my DefaultLogger is not configurable from outside the logger code which I think should be a feature.

Is my approach any good? How could I improve it?

Answer (score 3):

**Stop using double underscore.**
The double underscore is reserved for the implementation it definitely should not be used in "user code".

[See: What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065)

#### Recursive template Call.

You use a recursive technique to call the `Write()` method for all your sinks. I prefer to use the loop technique (I would say this is a more modern approach but I have no reference for that). But I find it clearer as you don't need the empty terminating function call.

```
private:
    using Tuple=std::tuple<Sinks...>;

    template<std::size_t... index>
    static void writeToLogs(char const* m, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, index...> const&)
    {
        auto ignore = {(std::get<index>(s_Sinks).Write(m),true)...};
    }

public:
    static void Log(const char* msg)
    {
        writeToLogs(msg, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
    }
```

#### Design

Everybody and their grandson tends to want to write a logger at some point in time. The trouble is we already have a good logger built into the `*nix` world (syslog). If you are not using syslog to do your logging **you are doing it wrong**.

It (syslog) already does everything you need to do and more and there is a whole ecosystem built around it for monitoring. Now there is nothing wrong with writing a wrapper around syslog but you have to be smart about it (the current ones are very smart).

```
Log(debug, getSomeMessage());
```

This should not call the function `getMessage()` if the debugging level is set to production. That would be a complete wast of time and resources as debug messages are currently being ignored.

Answer (score 2):

- The APIs you wrote could be tightened. Here is something bad that can be done with them:

  ```
  std::ofstream out{ "somefile.txt" };
  out << endlog; // bad code
  ```
- > ```
  > __stamp
  > ```

  This is a bad name. Depending on how you (and everyone else using this API) write client code, you may end up with conflicts between these APIs and standard library implementation APIs.

  As a rule, do not use symbols starting with an underscore, and especially not with underscores followed by a capital letter. They are reserved for standard library implementations by convention and you are violating the principle of least surprise.
- > ```
  > log::emit<Info, LevelStamp, SeparatorStamp, TimeStamp>() << ...
  > ```

  This is cumbersome to write out, and it will be cumbersome to maintain.

  Try following these guidelines:

  - if you have to write (mostly) the same line of code over and over again, extract it into a function (it will be one order of magnitude easier to maintain and change).
  - if you have code that should be extracted into a function, do so from the beginning (make it part of your logging API):

    ```
    namespace diagnostics // logging namespace example
    {
        inline auto info() {
            return log::emit<Info, LevelStamp, SeparatorStamp, TimeStamp>();
        }
        inline auto warn() {
            return log::emit<Warn, LevelStamp, SeparatorStamp, TimeStamp>();
        }
        inline auto error() {
           return log::emit<Error, LevelStamp, SeparatorStamp, TimeStamp>();
        }
    }
    ```

  client code:

  ```
  using endl = diagnostics::endlog;
  diagnostics::info() << "Hello, Logging " << 3 << endl;
  diagnostics::error() << "Mistakes were made ..." << endl;
  ```